# Embed dictionary data in YAML file into a state file

Tags: salt-stack

I'm looking to embed dictionary data in a YAML file into a state file as i have access to execute only state files.

Below is the dictionary data in YAML file.

```yaml
---
var1:
  values:
    val1: "string1"
    val2: "string2"
```

Below is the state file in which i have written YAML dictionary data as below.

```
{%- load_yaml as var %}
var1:
  values:
    val1: "string1"
    val2: "string2"
{%- endload %}
```

I'm not sure if this is right, can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, yaml file can be mentioned in state file as below.

```
{% load_yaml as values %}
    var1: 'string1'
    var2: 'string2'
{% endload %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `import_yaml` functionality.

YAML file `var.yml` with some variables:

```yaml
---
var1:
  values:
    val1: "string1"
    val2: "string2"
```

An `example.sls` state file:

```yaml
{% import_yaml 'path/to/var.yml' as var_data %}

show-imported-variables:
  module.run:
  - name: test.echo
  - text: {{ var_data['var1']['values'] }}
```

Now that the YAML file has been imported as `var_data` we can access the `values` within the dictionary.

When the state file is run:

```
----------
ret:
    ----------
    val1:
        string1
    val2:
        string2
```

Comment: I don't have access to other files, need to embed the code in state file only.
Need to use dictionary data inside state file and access the variables

Comment: So where is this YAML file which has dictionary data (as per your question)? Are you trying to reuse it, or asking how to create a variable with dictionary data in a state file?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question, dictionary data YAML file. Create a variable with dictionary data and use it in state file

Comment: When you say "*dictionary data in YAML file*", and "*don't have access to other files*" it sounds contradicting.